# How to add Views name to body class?

Tags: 7, views, theming

At moment Drupal add css class `page-VIEWPATH` to the body tag. How can I add css class `page-VIEWNAME` to the body tag without third party module or JQuery?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700838/adding-a-class-to-body

Comment: I had look at that post before, didn't find the answer I was looking for. I can't simply add $variables['classes_array'][] = 'new-class'; for the page that isn't the view page.

Comment: you can add a condition 
if (current_path() == 'my-path') {
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'new-class';
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out, this can be done with a combination of `hook_preprocess_html`  and `function views_get_page_view` to get a true `<body>` class for a given view and display ([see the API page](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_page_view/7)).

So wrapping it up within the `hook_preprocess_html` context, it would look something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 *
 * Misc page preprocess functions.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {

// Query the view and add a class
$view = views_get_page_view();
 if (
  isset($view) &&
  $view->name == 'actions' &&
  $view->current_display == "page"
) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'views-actions-page';
  }
}
```

So above, I query the view name and display and the key is `$view = views_get_page_view();`. This works great for custom Views body classes per view and display.

The rendered HTML result is something like this:

```
<body class="html not-front logged-in no-sidebars 
page-actions section-actions page-views flush-header views-actions-page">
```

** `views-actions-page` is the class that we added with the function above.

It should be noted that the advantage of this vs. using views generated classes are that if the URL of the page changes, your custom Views class will not whereas `page-actions section-actions` would change based on the URL. So using those classes could be unreliable if they are used for theming as it would have a negative ripple effect.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem. The note you described is exactly the problem I was facing. Thanks again!

Comment: @wzh - Welcome, glad that helped!

Comment: Do we have any alternative to ```$view = views_get_page_view();``` in drupal 8/9?

Comment: @TarunNagpal Look into `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('view_id');` You'll also need `use Drupal\views\Views;`

Answer (score 3):

Use the following function in `template.php` of your theme folder

```
function THEME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables){
    $view = $variables['view'];
    if($view->name == "YOUR_VIEW_NAME" && $view->current_display == "MACHINE_NAME_OF_VIEW"){
        $variables['classes_array'][]="page-".$view->name;
    }
}
```

you can also set some other conditions like `current_path` or anything else you want.

Comment: I tried something very similar earlier but it didn't work, just tried yours too and it didn't add the view name as class. Does $variables['classes_array'][] work on body class in preprocess_views_view? Because that is what I tried before. Thanks for reply.

Comment: You must clear the Drupal cache. I tried it on localhost before answering

Comment: This is very odd, I did clear the cache every time. Just for testing I got rid of IF statement and that is not working neither.

Comment: Print some text at the beginning of the function to make sure it get called and executed

Comment: It executed and print the text.

Comment: Include the `IF` statement and use `kpr($variables)` in the `IF` statement and see the `classes_array` array. That would be good if you take a screenshot of your code and the result of `kpr` and include them in the question

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question which is to add a *body* class based on the view name. All the function above does is add a class to the actual views HTML element within the page and not the `<body>` tag. The function above then is moot as you can use the Views UI CSS class field.

Comment: He can use class to filter body